# Batch Normalization results inconsistent across Keras and Tensorflow for toy example: why?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to get BatchNormalization working properly in Keras (2.2.4), and haven't had luck.  Its behavior seems inconsistent across `model.fit()` and `model.predict()`/`evaluate()`.

My original problem was in the context of a complex GAN setup with various layers that were switching between frozen and unfrozen.  In an attempt to grok why things were failing, I created this toy example, in which there is only a single BatchNormalization layer trying to learn the identity function, and there is no more freezing/unfreezing nonsense:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, BatchNormalization

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=(20,1,))
    y = x

    ip = tx =Input(shape=[1,])
    tx = BatchNormalization()(tx)
    mod = keras.Model(inputs=ip, outputs=tx)

    mod.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01), loss="mse")
    mod.fit(x, y, epochs=2000)
    print("mod evaluate", mod.evaluate(x, y))
```

I also created a pure tensorflow implementation that tries to do the exact same thing:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=(20,1))
    y = x

    input = tx = tf.Variable(initial_value=x)
    is_training = tf.Variable(initial_value=False)
    tx = tf.layers.batch_normalization(tx, training=is_training)
    output = tx
    train_output = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))

    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(train_output, output)
    train_op = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9).minimize(loss)
    train_op = tf.group([train_op, update_ops])

    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    is_training.load(False, sess)
    py = sess.run(output)
    print("py", py)
    print("mse", np.mean(np.square(py - x)))

    print("training...")
    for i in range(2000):
        is_training.load(True, sess)
        sess.run(train_op, {train_output: y})

        is_training.load(False, sess)
        py = sess.run(output)
        print("step", i, "mse", np.mean(np.square(py - x)))

    is_training.load(False, sess)
    py = sess.run(output)
    print("mse", np.mean(np.square(py - x)))
```

I expect the Keras and Tensorflow results to be similar.  But the Keras code prints out a MSE error approx 0.0002 at the end, while showing a loss of about 1e-12 during training.  The Tensorflow code gives a way lower error, at approx 1e-16 for both training and test.  The Tensorflow result is the expected one, since it should be trivial to learn the identity function, and once the moving mean and variance of BN converge, the results should be identical across train/test.

Why is this happening?  Why is the behavior inconsistent across Tensorflow and Keras, and how can I get a lower error using pure Keras?  Any insight into the situation would be appreciated.